# Can I run CNTK on Intel Nervana Neural Network Processor (NNP)?

Tags: cntk

Can I run **CNTK** on Intel **Nervana Neural Network Processor** (NNP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not supported at the moment.

According to cha-zhang, on this recent github Issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2519) the team is collaborating with Intel on this, but they don't have dates.